Alignt text left and center in ListView
In flutter, how would you align different length text to the left and in center of a List view builder? I have tried column, align and text align but in vain.

Can you show a visual representation of your question to get the better understanding of your question?

Do you want the text to be aligned to the left or centered based on its length? Did you try Center() widget?

I have a list of 5 to 15 char long strings and would like to show them  left-aligned in the center of the page;  ie. each string should start at the same x coordinate. The only solution I have found is to wrap the list in a fixed width Sizedbox and center the box in a column. Is there  a better solution?

There are different solutions for this. The most important thing is how your layout will look on different screen sizes.
I provided two examples, one with Padding and one with the Position widgets.
Both solutions provide the same result as shown in the screenshot below.
Let me know if it's suitable for your case.

 class ExampleWithPositionWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const ExampleWithPositionWidget({
    super.key,
  });

  final _percentageFromScreenEdge = 0.1; // 10%.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(
          left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * _percentageFromScreenEdge,
          right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * _percentageFromScreenEdge,
          top: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.blue.withAlpha(50),
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: differentLengthStrings.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final item = differentLengthStrings[index];
                return Text(item);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}



class ExampleWithPadding extends StatelessWidget {
  const ExampleWithPadding({
    super.key,
  });

  final double _horizontalPadding = 0.10; // 10% of the screen width

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Center(
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: screenWidth * _horizontalPadding,
        ),
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.blue.withAlpha(50),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: differentLengthStrings.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    final item = differentLengthStrings[index];
                    return Text(item);
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

